# How to install coco dataset in colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have coco dataset(19 gb), the dataset upload googledrive but colab is not find this data despite use this code import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'content/gdrive/My Drive/caption').How can I find this file?

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'content/gdrive/My Drive/caption')

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need a leading `/` in your path. (Typically, the Drive FUSE mount path is `/content/...`)